# EXC_BAD_ACCESS what is the object getting released twice?

Tags: iphone, ios, exc-bad-access, nsautoreleasepool

These are the screenshots from Zombie Profiling:
[image: released to ref count 0]
[image: realesed to ref count -1]
How do I know, which object was getting released earlier, which is again getting released in the pool drain?

I am using ARC, with `@autoreleasepool {}` in some methods

Comment: Now you have ARC, earlier you had autorelease. If you are not sure about releasing / retaining, try these.

Answer (score 0):

Please check ur class named BackgroundSync with the no of releases and no of allocations.
remember no of released objects should be equal to no of allocated objects.

1) You might have release some objects in dealloc .
2) you might have releases some objects in the particular functions listed in the above instruments list so check them first.